# Reading an internal file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio

I am writing to an internal file in Android Studio

```
 String filename = "output.txt";
            String fileContents = studentNum + ", " + lastName + ", " + firstName + ", " + radioValue + ", " + spinnerInfo + "\n"; // edit this to include all content
            FileOutputStream outputStream;

            try{
                outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                outputStream.write(fileContents.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The code lets me write lines of data split with commas. I am able to then go to another activity and read it all out at once.

```
  String file = "output.txt";
        String line = "";
        String data = "";

        //File read operation
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(file);  //A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis); //An InputStreamReader is a bridge from byte streams to character streams
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);    //Reads text from a character-input stream,
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                data += (counter+1) + "\t"+ line +"\n";
                counter++;
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Show the data
        txtOutput.setText(data);
```

However I want to be able to read only one line of data per activity and when I click a button it transfers down to the next line of data. And goes in a carousel loop so once we reach the last line it will go to the first line of data once the button is clicked again

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is probably just to keep a line number pointer (since you are reading by line), and read down that many lines to get where you want at each activity. If the file is large or you are otherwise performance conscious this is not a great option.

Both `InputStream` and `Reader` have a `skip(<bytes>)` method. You could also do it that way. Obviously if you use a stream you need to read by bytes not by line, so a little more trouble.

You could also use a `RandomAccessFile` that has a `seek()` method. Again this is accessed by byte index.